# Accidentally installed two versions of Python 3.4.1... Can't run any scripts, no modules can import, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.4

I was having problems with a 'zlib' import error on Python3.4.1, so I followed the instructions [here,](http://joequery.me/guides/python26-no-module-zlib/) but instead of doing it for Python 2.6 I did it for 3.4. I had not uninstalled my existing version of Python3.4 before doing this new installation process. I can now import zlib, however all of my custom packages cannot be imported, such as sklearn, scipy, numpy, flask, and pandas.

First, I get an import error:

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

So, I try to remedy the issue with:

```
pip3 install scipy
```

But, I am greeted with:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-
packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from scipy)
```

I tried running `echo $PYTHONPATH` but it returned blank.

I can import sys, os, time, and zlib just fine. It just won't import all of the dependencies that I already have on my computer.

I tried deleting the folder in /tmp where I installed the "newer" Python3.4.1 folder, however this did not work. I don't know how to fix this issue.

I can still run python scripts in an anaconda virtual environment that I had created a while ago, but I can't use virtualenv's, which is a problem since I use zappa a lot (which requires an active virtualenv).

This is what I get when I try to run a virtualenv:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fb1bc7f4740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The python version that contains all of my dependencies in dist-packages is located in /usr/local/bin/python3.4. How can I make it so that when I run `python3` that it will use the dependencies from that folder? Is the fact that the pythonpath variable is blank bad?

I just want my old python back.

PS. Everything works fine for python2. It's just causing these issues for python3.

Comment: Was your old Python 3 from the pertinent Ubuntu package? If so, you should reinstall that package, after making sure you've deleted any executables under the `python3` name (ie. `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`) not included in it.

Comment: I also strongly advise against following the instructions on the page you linked. Much safer to build and install only the single module, or -- if you must -- to rebuild the distro package *as a Debian package* rather than shadow it with a direct hand-built installation. If your employer has sysadmin staff conversant in supporting Debian-derived operating systems, they should be able to help.

Comment: I had already followed the instructions on the page that I have linked, which is why I am now experiencing issues... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but with another package.  In my case it turned out that I had a egg-info file present in the site-packages without the directory for the package.  Deleting the egg-info file (actually I moved it first) allowed a clean install to occur.